# sql query times out...case / if / what to do

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sql server sproc:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSoftwareProgramsGrid]
    @SoftwareTitle varchar(1000)='All',
    @CategoryID varchar(100)='All',
    @ManufacturerID varchar(50)='All',
    @ModelID int=0, -- 0 means all
    @AssetID int=0, -- 0 means all
    @AssetStatus int=0, --0 is active, 1 is inactive, and 2 is all
    @Status int=0, --0 is active, 1 is inactive, and 2 is all
    @Type varchar(100)='All',
    @Site varchar(100)='All',
    @Department varchar(100)='All',
    @Manager varchar(100)='All',
    @Employee varchar(100)='All',
    @SortExpression varchar(100)='Software',
    @SortOrder int=0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Program AS Software
    FROM
        AssetProgram ap
    LEFT JOIN
        AssetAssignment aa
    ON
        aa.AssetID = ap.AssetID
    LEFT JOIN
        [MyLinkedServer].MyDB.dbo.Login l
    ON
        l.LoginID = aa.LoginID
    LEFT JOIN
        Asset a
    ON
        a.AssetID = ap.AssetID
    INNER JOIN Model m
    ON
        a.ModelID = m.ModelID
    INNER JOIN
        Category c
    ON
        c.CategoryID = m.CategoryID
    INNER JOIN Manufacturer ma 
    ON
        ma.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
    WHERE
        (
            --Software filters
            (ap.Program = @SoftwareTitle OR @SoftwareTitle='All')

            --Asset filters
            AND (c.CategoryID = @CategoryID OR @CategoryID='All')   --filter category
            AND (ma.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID OR @ManufacturerID='All') --filter manufacturer
            AND (m.ModelID = @ModelID OR @ModelID = 0)  --filter model
            AND (a.AssetID = @AssetID OR @AssetID = 0)  --filter by asset name (the actual asset id)
            AND (((a.Inactive=@AssetStatus) OR (@AssetStatus=2)))
            AND (aa.Inactive=0) 
            AND (ap.Inactive=0)

            --Employee filters
            /*AND ((l.Inactive=@Status) OR (@Status=2)) --status of employee 2 is all, 1 is inactive, and 0 is active

            AND (@Type='All' OR (@Type='Contractor' AND l.IsContractor=1) OR (@Type='Regular' AND l.IsContractor=0))    --contractor or regular employee
            AND (@Site='All' OR @Site=l.ClientID)   --the site
            AND (@Department='All' OR @Department=l.FunctionalGroupID)  --the department
            AND ((l.Manager = @Manager OR l.FullName=@Manager) OR @Manager='All')   --the manager
            AND (l.FullName = @Employee OR @Employee='All') --the employee
            */
        )) ttt
ORDER BY    
            CASE WHEN @SortExpression='Software' AND @SortOrder=0 THEN Software END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SortExpression='Software' AND @SortOrder=1 THEN Software END DESC
```

This query has to include a linked server, due to our setup.  The query runs fine and is fast as long as I comment out my employee parameters, namely this section:

```
--Employee filters
                /*AND ((l.Inactive=@Status) OR (@Status=2)) --status of employee 2 is all, 1 is inactive, and 0 is active

                AND (@Type='All' OR (@Type='Contractor' AND l.IsContractor=1) OR (@Type='Regular' AND l.IsContractor=0))    --contractor or regular employee
                AND (@Site='All' OR @Site=l.ClientID)   --the site
                AND (@Department='All' OR @Department=l.FunctionalGroupID)  --the department
                AND ((l.Manager = @Manager OR l.FullName=@Manager) OR @Manager='All')   --the manager
                AND (l.FullName = @Employee OR @Employee='All') --the employee
                */
```

The minute I bring even the first line of that section in, for example just this one:

`AND ((l.Inactive=@Status) OR (@Status=2))`

The entire sproc hangs (times out)....I've properly indexed my tables and I even have an index on the `Inactive` field within my linked table...If I take that same line above and just say:

`AND (l.Inactive=0)`

It runs fine, so the OR condition is causing it (boolean).  However, I need this condition as a parameter is passed that needs to be satisfied.  What are my other options, do I have to `IF BEGIN...` using all these parameters?  It seems cumbersome...For anyones information the AssetProgram table has a total of 50k rows, so that isn't too much.

Comment: Check your query plans. I bet that the ORs are causing a index scans instead of seeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah your where clause is crazy, specially with all the "OR"s

try to load your "users" into a temp table (or var table) based on the @Status variable (if it is 1 you load only inactive, if it is 0 you load only actives and so on...) and use the temp table on the join, that will drastically decrease the number of comparisons.

Comment: I tried that with this....`if (@Status = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Users(LoginID, Inactive)
SELECT LoginID, Inactive FROM [TKKAH-SQL-1].TKKCommonData.dbo.Login l WHERE (l.Inactive=0 AND l.HireDate IS NOT NULL)
END

else if (@Status = 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Users(LoginID, Inactive)
SELECT LoginID, Inactive FROM [TKKAH-SQL-1].TKKCommonData.dbo.Login l WHERE (l.Inactive=1 AND l.HireDate IS NOT NULL)
END

else
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Users(LoginID, Inactive)
SELECT LoginID, Inactive FROM [TKKAH-SQL-1].TKKCommonData.dbo.Login l WHERE (l.HireDate IS NOT NULL)
END` but the result is I still need this...

Comment: `AND ((l.Inactive=@Status) OR (@Status=2))` if I do not include the `AND` the query always returns the same # of software titles...maybe because it is a left join...err